# Does rails form_for use the same route when using a symbol or instance var?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is just a general question about the helper "form_for". I'm working on a program out of a textbook which has a form file using `<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>`. The form is shared by the new and edit template. However, I've seen a lot of tutorials using a symbol (:product) instead of the instance variable. So, I tried swapping them to see what would happen. As it happens it gives me a routing error when trying to submit a form:

```
No route matches [POST] "/products/new"
```

and

```
No route matches [POST] "/products/5/edit"
```

Here's the code:

```
    <%= form_for(:product) do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and in the product_controller

```
 def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I thought I had read that "form_for :product" would search for an instance variable of the same name and use the same route, product_path, but it seems I was mistaken. I've looked at other posts on this site, but they don't seem to mention the routes. Why I'm getting this error?

EDIT: I added the option "url: products_path" to the form_for :product line and it works now. I'm guessing the symbol doesn't know to use the routes in resources like @product does?

Comment: hmmm, that doesnt seem to explain the routing issue. Only the tag change

Comment: If you have a routing error, please check the file `confg/routes.rb` it must include `resources :products`. If not, add it and restart the server.

Comment: It's there. Does using a symbol count as a resource? I know using @ does and would know the paths.

Comment: If the symbol was instantiated as an object just as it is with `@` then yes it will have the same behaviour for routes.  The object in a form_for will call a POST (or possibly a patch) unless you define how you want the form_for method to post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a routing error, please check the file confg/routes.rb it must include resources :products. If not, add it and restart the server.

And yes at routes we use a symbol with the table name (plural of model) for define resources.

edited:

With form_for use an instance variable: @product that was initialized on controller with an empty new product, or the finded product to update.